# Meaning of System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am working on a SharePoint 2007 related application.

I use SharePoint build-in web services to interact with SharePoint server’s content, but some time to time I am going EndpointNotFoundException exception.

Can somebody tell me why I am getting this exception?

Thanks

Comment: most likely you have a wrong endpoint address somewhere - or that endpoint might not be available at all times (e.g. the service providing that endpoint might be down at times)